# The origin of the term "Frobenius norm"

Tags: reference-request, math-history

How did the name Frobenius get attached to "Frobenius norm" of a matrix? I could not find any work of his that uses the norm.

Comment: Good question!  While we are at it, how about "Frobenius inner product" as well.

Comment: Frobenius endomorphism, Frobenius automorphism, [Frobenius number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNumber.html) ...For his works, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Georg_Frobenius).

Comment: In general, see Thomas Hawkins, [The Mathematics of Frobenius in Context : A Journey Through 18th to 20th Century Mathematics (Springer, 2013)](https://books.google.it/books?id=UzTBBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover). But I cannot find in the Index an entry on "F norm".

Comment: According to [Tripod site](http://jeff560.tripod.com/n.html) the use of "norm" regarding matrix dates around 1940.

Comment: Mauro, Thank you for the references. Clearly, during the lifetime of Frobenius nobody wrote about the "norm of a matrix". I tried to find at least the expression $(\sum a_{ij}^2)^{1/2}$ in the book, but without success.The expression can be found in Peano's "Intégration par séries des équations différentielles linéaires" from 1887. I wonder if anyone has seen it in the work of Frobenius? His name is associated with series solutions of differential equations.